# verifying a single attendee with email

Tags: eventbrite

Is there a method to return a specific attendee's information by sending:

1) the attendee's email address

2) my user_key

3) my app_key

I could do this by searching the returned xml from this "event_list_attendees" method, however, I would prefer to only receive the one result (not hundreds for each call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: I work on the platform team at Eventbrite

Currently there is no way to search for a specific attendee with `event_list_attendees`.

However, you can cut down on the amount of data returned by paging through the results until you have found the attendee or using the `modified_after` parameter if you know when the user was last updated: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_list_attendees/

I realize this limitation is non-ideal.  We're actively working on building a new API which is more RESTful and does not have issues like this.